# Is it correct to say "the tiny ball is just around the corner of the drawer"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

[image]

Look at the diagram above.

**A drawer was taken out and is on the floor.**

The little boy is looking for the tiny ball. The ball happens at the back of the drawer. The boy is standing on the right side of the drawer.

We often use "**just around the corner**" when talking about **street corners** or "**room corners**".

I am not sure we can use it with **corners of a wardrobe or a drawer?**

Is it correct to say "**the tiny ball is just around the corner of the drawer**"?

Comment: I would say _behind_ a large piece of furniture like a wardrobe, or _down the back of_ a drawer. Of course, we don't normally see into the space behind a drawer unless we pull it right out, but things can accidentally get pushed over into that space.

Comment: Drawers are inserted into furniture using a slide or guide. https://www.woodgears.ca/drawers/index.html No ball can be behind a drawer. It falls to the floor when the drawer is **open or opened**. In any case, "around the corner" is wrong,

Comment: Also, a tiny ball could not be there since there is no opening for it to fall there while the drawer is in the piece of furniture. If the drawer is on the floor, the ball is just behind it.

Comment: Finally, if the drawer is on the floor, and the ball is behind it, the kid can see it from above.  He or she won't need help locating it.

Answer (score 2):

Grammatically the sentence is fine, but I think that many English speakers would find it a bit strange for two reasons:

1. Saying that something is "just" somewhere often implies that if you go a little further, then you will encounter it. That is why when an infant crawls toward his mother, you can say, "You're almost there . . . Go just a little further!" However, even children are usually too big to walk around drawers.
2. Even children can usually just look over the top of a drawer instead of around the corner.

However, let's say that a blind boy was feeling around the drawer to try to find the ball. If he was feeling the side of the drawer, you could say, "Move your fingers a little further . . . The ball is just around the corner!"

Comment: Sorry, but there really isn't any such thing as an object being "around the corner of a drawer". Also, if a drawer is in place, this is impossible. And if the drawer has been pulled out and is on the floor, the ball is merely behind it.

Comment: @Lambie As I indicated in my post, I agree that it's unusual to say "around the corner of a drawer", but I think that it could be acceptable in some situations. Oh well, we all speak our language a bit differently!

Comment: This OP always tries to ask trick questions. Please bear in mind what I said in my first comment. In what situation would a ball be "behind a drawer"? And how could any kid be standing to the right of a drawer? Unless it is pulled out part way, in which case, the ball would fall to the ground inside the furniture. Or, it would be stuck, and then the kid cannot see it nor can any adult present see it. This really has zero to do with "how we speak our language"; it has to do with how furniture and drawers "work".

Comment: @Lambie Yes, I think we are 99% in agreement. The only situation I thought of that might work was the one with a blind person feeling around the drawer with his fingers. I think that you might then say that the ball was just around the corner, implying that he needed to move his fingers just a little further to get there. I acknowledge that it's a bit of an edge case.

Comment: What do you mean by feeling "around the drawer"? Generally, people feel around inside a drawer when the drawer is open. And even for a blind person, the drawer would have to be placed on the floor or a table for a ball to be behind it.

Comment: @Lambie, the drawer was taken out and is on the floor.

Comment: @Tom Then, it could be a huge box and does not need to be a "drawer".  All that is just a red herring.

Comment: @Lambie Agreed. I have no idea why OP made it specifically a drawer.